# function inadvertently executed when using .live in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, dynamic, livequery

I'm trying to bind a click event handler to some elements that are being created dynamically.
But the function already gets executed on simply loading the page.
I also tried the livequery plugin and .delegate which also had that unwanted habit.

```
$(".pika_thumb").live("click" ,( function () {
    $("#video").hide();
    $(".pika_main").show();
}));
```

How do I prevent my function to be executed on other events than a click on the specified elements?

Comment: The parentheses around the function are unneeded but shouldn't cause the issue described.  I would imagine there's something else on your page causing this problem.  Try placing an alert inside this click function and see if it is displayed on load.

Comment: I had an alert inside it and did fire.

Comment: The parentheses seemed to actually cause the function to execute. I should have looked more closely to the example code.

Comment: Very strange.  Which browser were you testing it in?  I had tried it in chrome just to see and it didn't fire.

Comment: I was testing with Firefox 3.6.16, Chromium 10.0.630.0 and Opera prior to 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only obvious error is the brackets from around the `function() { }` definition.

However that wouldn't cause immediate invocation unless you had trailing a `()` parameter list too.  Is your code snippet complete?

Answer (score 0):

the syntax:

```
$(".pika_thumb").live("click" , function () {
    $("#video").hide();
    $(".pika_main").show();
});
```

check if you don't have something else that fires the click on your .pika_thumb class.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the brackets, my final working code is:

```
$("#gallery").delegate(".pika_thumb", "mousedown" , function () {
    $(".video-js").get(0).pause();
    $("#video").hide();
    $(".pika_main").show();
});
```

Thanks everyone!